# Thread.sleep blocks other Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Output class which just prints everything that it gets to print.

```
public class Output {
    private static List<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Output output = null;

    private Output() {
        Runnable task = () -> {
            int lastIndex = 0;

            while (true) {
                while (lastIndex < textList.size()) {
                    System.out.println(lastIndex + " - " + textList.size() + ": " + textList.get(lastIndex));

                    outputText(textList.get(lastIndex));

                    lastIndex ++;
                }
            }
        };

        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    private static void outputText(String text) {
        synchronized (System.out) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }

    }

    public static void say(String text) {
        if (output == null) {
            output = new Output();
        }

        textList.add(text);
    }
}
```

When I add something to print, everything works fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Output.say("" + i);
}
```

But when I add a `Thread.sleep` to the loop it stops on the first output:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Output.say("" + i);
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

How can I prevent it? I mean, I'm stopping with sleep just the main thread and not the separate thread.

Comment: Unclear, where you add the loops? Where the second thread?

Comment: 1) I don't understand the logic in `say` _at all_; why do you need an instance of `Output` to access a `static` variable? Note that starting threads in constructors is generally not a good idea. 2) I don't see a `synchronized` block anywhere on mutating `textList`; from the [JavaDoc for `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) "_**Note that this implementation is not synchronized**_" (emphasis theirs)

Comment: The first thread is the normal main method and the second thread starts in the Output constructor. My mistake, I removed the instance of `Output` in `say`. I know that ArrayList is not synchronized, but I don't know how to solve it differently.

Comment: Use a collection specifically designed for the task, like a [`BlockingQueue`](https://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html). This also has the benefit of removing the busy wait from your code.

Comment: Starting a thread in a constructor usually is a bad idea.  Google for "safe publication" and "leaking _this_."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don’t synchronize threads correctly, there is no guaranty that threads see updates made by other threads. They may either completely miss updates or see only parts of them, creating an entirely inconsistent result. Sometimes they may even *appear* to do the right thing. Without proper synchronization (in the sense of any valid construct specified to be thread safe), this is entirely unpredictable.

Sometimes, the chances of seeing a particular behavior are higher, like in your example. In most runs, the loop without `sleep` will complete before the other thread even starts its work, whereas inserting `sleep` raises the chance of lost updates after the second thread has seen values. Once the second thread has seen a value for `textList.size()`, it might reuse the value forever, evaluating `lastIndex < textList.size()` to `false` and executing the equivalent of `while(true) { }`.

It’s funny that the only place where you inserted a construct for thread safety, is the method `outputText` that is called by a single thread only (and printing to `System.out` is synchronized internally in most environments anyway).

Besides, it’s not clear why you are creating an object of type `Output` that has no relevance here, as all fields and methods are `static`.

Your code can be corrected and simplified to

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();
    new Thread( () -> {
        int index=0;
        while(true) synchronized(textList) {
            for(; index<textList.size(); index++)
                System.out.println(textList.get(index));
        }
    }).start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        synchronized(textList) {
            textList.add(""+i);
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

though it still contains the issues of you original code of never terminating due to the infinite second thread and also burning the CPU with a polling loop. You should let the second thread *wait* for new items and add a termination condition:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();
    new Thread( () -> {
        synchronized(textList) {
            for(int index=0; ; index++) {
                while(index>=textList.size()) try {
                    textList.wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) { return; }
                final String item = textList.get(index);
                if(item==null) break;
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }).start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        synchronized(textList) {
            textList.add(""+i);
            textList.notify();
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    synchronized(textList) {
        textList.add(null);
        textList.notify();
    }
}
```

This is still only an academic example that you shouldn’t use in real life code. There are classes for thread safe data exchange provided by the Java API removing the burden of implementing such things yourself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayBlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    String endMarker = "END-OF-QUEUE"; // the queue does not allow null
    new Thread( () -> {
        for(;;) try {
            String item = queue.take();
            if(item == endMarker) break;// don't use == for ordinary strings
            System.out.println(item);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) { return; }
    }).start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        queue.put(""+i);
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    queue.put(endMarker);
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your example. Could you please explain `for(;;) try { ... }` please?

Comment: `for(;;)` does the same as `while(true)`. I tried to avoid it in the first example, keeping it like in your code, however, I’m so used to it that it slipped through in the last one. There is no real difference between `for(;;)` and `while(true)`.